# Issue with Silverlight Pivotviewer control

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I am having a silverlight pivotviewer control in a sharepoint page. This Pivotviewer talks to a web service hosted under sharepoint to fetch cxml/dzi/dzc. Everything is fine as long as its in http. Once on https - the CXML and dzc responses come out fine, but the dzi never happens - no images come up.Can anyone let me know why this is happening - and how to fix this?

Note: The Image directory is also under the same Sharepoint site - its a virtual directory. So even this is under ssl. If I configure the image path {for forming dzi} to another http virtual directory, everything works fine. But it simply doesn't work for a https virtual directory under the SP site.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work as I've done exactly that (using https) for http://percollate.com. Is it possible that https is bound to something unexpected on your IIS server? Have you tried using Fiddler to see what's happening?